# Navigation Design for GoogleTV

Tags: gui-design, navigation, android, guidelines

I'm doing some research on ways to navigate on a GoogleTV.

There aren't any design guidelines, but it seems a Left Menu Bar design, like the GTv YouTube app, is common use. 
In my opinion it doesn't feel right.

My question: what is a good way to navigate between different screens within a GoogleTV app.

Comment: You need to narrow your question down to a single UX issue. Right now it is too broad to answer well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some official recommendations by Google:

- [Google TV Design Patterns](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_patterns) and
- [Designing for TV](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/design_for_tv)

So left navigation is not only common use but the equivalent to the ActionBar on GTV. You should deviate only when you have a very good reason!

Comment: From that link: TVs are always in "landscape".
On a TV, available space runs left-to-right rather than top-to-bottom. Put on-screen navigational controls on the left or right side of the screen and save vertical space for content.